# Where should theoretical questions about the internet go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about how the internet/web works (leaning towards the higher levels on the OSI model). I know Pro Webmasters is about a specific problem regarding the web, but how about theoretical?

Is it CS.SE? The tour says that questions about "**computer architecture, networks**" belong there.

Or Super User? The tour says:

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe [networkengineering.SE]. As always, check their Help Center to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [help-center of Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Computer science, also sometimes called computing science, is the
>   science of computation and its applications. This site covers
>   **theoretical** and applied computer science at any level, including but
>   not limited to:
>
> - **algorithms, models of computation**
> - programming language semantics, formal methods
> - **computer architecture, networks**
> - machine learning, artificial intelligence, knowledge representation,
> - natural language processing
> - vision, graphics

So, yeah the most suitable site for your question should be the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hope you don't mind me bolding theoretical and one-boxing the quote.

Comment: @PolyGeo I always do that with my answers.  Wonder how I missed in this one.  Thanks for the edit :)